# Cannot install or build virtualbox kernel driver in Ubuntu 11.10 64bit

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-11.10

I'm trying to install `virtualbox-4.1` (from the virtualbox.org apt source) on Ubuntu 11.10 and it will not install the kernel driver:

```
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
 * Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules                       [ OK ] 
 * Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS                  Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.0.0-16-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.8/build/make.log for more information.

 * Failed, trying without DKMS
 * Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                                        
 * Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong
```

the `vbox-install.log` contains:

```
Uninstalling modules from DKMS
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.8/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxhost-4.1.8

DKMS: add Completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.0.0-16-generic -C /lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.8/build....(bad exit status: 2)
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (    \
    echo;                               \
    echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo;                               \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-16-generic/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated -Iinclude  -include include/generated/autoconf.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m64 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -I/lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(SUPDrv_linux)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxdrv)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/.tmp_SUPDrv-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-16-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-16-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/vm86.h:130,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-16-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:10,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-16-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:22,
                 from include/linux/thread_info.h:53,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:9,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/linux/../SUPDrvInternal.h:103,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:31:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-16-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h:148:23: fatal error: asm/cache.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make: *** [vboxdrv] Error 2
```

I've reinstalled the linux headers and the cache.h file does not appear in this directory. 
Should it be trying to use `x86` sources or `ia64`?

This appears to be because of [line 26](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-oneiric.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h;h=cd84f7208f76b5066f96969c687d1c214e5e3b9a;hb=e1c01a2eeb0467d3f4231c6fb8cb994aabb2a6f0#l26) and [lines 146-147](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-oneiric.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h;h=cd84f7208f76b5066f96969c687d1c214e5e3b9a;hb=e1c01a2eeb0467d3f4231c6fb8cb994aabb2a6f0#l147) of the x86 `segment.h` header which are:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_X86_32
```

and

```
#else
#include <asm/cache.h>
```

Is this a kernel bug or should I be forcing some 64bit compilation?

*Update: I now think the arch is correct - `uname -a` yeilds*

`Linux stephenk 3.0.0-16-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 27 17:44:39 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I lost some files.  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-3.0.0.16-generic` did not work, but

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.0.0.16
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.0.0.16-generic
```

did.  Presumably all I needed to do was

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-3.0.0.16
```

After this, `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` works and my VMs can launch.